# Nested directive within ng-view doesn't work AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I developing a SPA using the native directive from angular ng-view to change views, the problem is that One of those views there is a custom directive I've wrote and when the route is loaded the directive doesnt work.

Here it is the config method of the App and the custom directive that doesn't fire up :S

```
climbingApp.config(
        function( $routeProvider ){
            $routeProvider.

            when('/', {
                controller: 'AppCtrl'
            }).

            when('/newSector', {
                template: '<formNewSector></formNewSector>',
                controller: 'addSector',
            }).

            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
        }
    );


climbingApp.directives

        .directive(
            'formNewSector',
            function() {

                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    template: "<div>gato</div>",
                    replace: true,
                    link: function( scope, iElement, iAttrs ){

                    }
                }
    });
```

Comment: Can you put your markup here also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled markup for directive in your `template`. For directive named `formNewSector` it should be `<form-new-sector>`, not `<formNewSector>`.