# Nested directive within ngView does not work Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, route-provider

I'm having exact problem as this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390425/nested-directive-within-ng-view-doesnt-work-angularjs). Nested directive does not work with ngview and routeconfig. But my problem is not related to syntax.

**I have defined modules as below:**

```
angular.module('hiDashboard', []);
angular.module('hiFramework', ['hiDashboard']);
angular.module('app', ['hiFramework']);
```

**Config code:**

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($routeProvider) {
  var routes = [
    {
      url: '/dashboard',
      config: { template: '<wwa-dashboard></wwa-dashboard>' }
    },
    {
      url: '/friends',
      config: { template: '<wwa-friends></wwa-friends>' }
    },
    {
      url: '/favouriteList',
      config: { template: '<wwa-favourite-list></wwa-favourite-list>' }
    }
  ];
  routes.forEach(function (route) {
    $routeProvider.when(route.url, route.config);
  });

   $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'});

});
```

**wwaDashboard Directive**

```
"use strict";
angular.module('app').directive('wwaDashboard', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {},
    template: '<hi-dashboard></hi-dashboard>',
    link: function (scope) {

    }
  };
});
```

**hiDashboard directive**

```
"use strict";
angular.module('hiDashboard').directive('hiDashboard', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    tempalte: 'This is dashboard directive'
  };
});
```

**Actual HTML Code**

```
<div ng-view class="hi-dashboard-view"></div>
```

**HTML Code when viewed from Developer Tools**

```
<div ng-view class="hi-dashboard-view ng-scope">
 <wwa-dashboard class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <hi-dashboard></hi-dashboard>
</wwa-dashboard>
</div>
```

**Expected HTML:**

```
<div ng-view class="hi-dashboard-view ng-scope">
 <wwa-dashboard class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <hi-dashboard>This is dashboard directive</hi-dashboard>
</wwa-dashboard>
</div>
```

**Problem:**
I do not see any errors in console but `<hi-dashboard>` content `'This is dashboard directive'` is not displayed in the browser. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template is spelled incorrectly in your directive:

`tempalte: 'This is dashboard directive'`

should be

`template: 'This is dashboard directive'`